# Print with angular

Tags: angular, printing

thanks for stopping here .

```
downloadHandler(id) {
        // this.isResultsLoading = true;
        this.invoiceService.downloadInvoice(id).subscribe(
            (data) => {
                console.log(data);
                saveAs(data, this.invoice.item);
                // saveAs(data, this.invoice.item);
            },
            (err) => {
                console.error(err);
                //this.errorHandler(err, 'Error while downloading invoice');
            }
        );
    }
```

i use this function to download and it works good ,
for now i can download my file then i print it .
my quetion is : i need to view the file to print with out downloading it .

thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: get the content.

```
this._http.get('http://localhost:4200/')
```

Make the response as arrayBuffer or blob as josn;

```
this._http.get('http://localhost:4200/', { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).
          or
this._http.get('some api end point', { responseType: 'blob' as 'json' }).
```

Step 2: Create a blob object

```
const myBlobPart: BlobPart = <BlobPart>res;
const file = new Blob([myBlobPart], { type: 'your media type' });
// media type can be : text/csv, application/pdf, text/plain etc.
```

Step 3: Create a url to the blob object.

```
    const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

STEP 4: Open the url

```
    window.open(fileURL);
```

So the complete solution will be something like this:

```
this._http.get('some api endpoint', { responseType: 'blob' as 'json'}).subscribe(res => {
    const myBlobPart: BlobPart = <BlobPart>res;
    const file = new Blob([myBlobPart], { type: 'your media type' });
    const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    console.log(fileURL);
    window.open(fileURL);
    this.url = fileURL;
});
```

Comment: Shadab Faiz , thanks for the answer , can u please explain more ?? i need a function to load the file then print it :) , am sorry iam new to angular .

Comment: I have update my answer with better logic and added explanation also.

Comment: Shadab Faiz , thanks alot , am working on it :) will let you know .

Comment: Shadab Faiz , can't make it so far . am still trying :) , this is my first app MEANSTACK  , not easy at all :p

Comment: where are you stuck?

Comment: Shadab Faiz ,  i got it working ,thank you very much

Comment: OMG now am stacking on CSS style won't load from backend !!!! ahhhhhh thats crazy ,after fixing one thing i get an other problem :)

Answer (score 0):

i got it to work ,so i share the approach it may help some one else

Service.ts

```
printInvoice(id: string) {
    this.httpClient.get('${BASE_URL}/invoices/${id}', { responseType: 'blob' as 'json' }).subscribe((res) => {
        const invoice: Invoice = <Invoice>res;
        const file = new Blob([ invoice ], { type: 'html' });
        const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        console.log(fileURL);
        window.open(fileURL);
    });
}
```

Component.ts

```
printHandler(id) {
    this.invoiceService.downloadInvoice(id).subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(this.printHandler);
        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(res);
        window.open(fileURL);
    });
}
```

and finaly HTML

```
<button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="printHandler(invoice._id)">Print</button>
```